# expected value of highest random pick from 5 different functions

Tags: probability

I have 5 functions: easy(), normal(), hard(), impossible() & insane(). Each has a different domain ([1,10], [10,25], [25,100], [200,500] & [500,100]).

```
easy       (x)  = 1  * 3600/( X * 3.6 + 60 )
normal     (x)  = 2  * 3600/( X * 3.6 + 60 )
hard       (x)  = 4  * 3600/( X * 3.6 + 60 )
impossible (x)  = 10 * 3600/( X * 3.6 + 60 )
insane     (x)  = 25 * 3600/( X * 3.6 + 60 )
```

Calculated values:

```
|               | min   | Q1    | Q2    | Q3    | max   |
|------------   |------ |------ |------ |------ |------ |
| easy          | 56,6  | 50,2  | 45,1  | 41,0  | 37,5  |
| normal        | 75,0  | 65,8  | 58,5  | 52,7  | 48,0  |
| hard          | 96,0  | 66,2  | 50,5  | 40,9  | 34,3  |
| impossible    | 46,2  | 34,3  | 27,3  | 22,6  | 19,4  |
| insane        | 48,4  | 39,0  | 32,6  | 28,0  | 24,6  |
```

linechart_1 shows each of these functions with their domains matched by min, Q1, Q2, Q3 & max values:

[image: img removed because too little reputation:]

Now:

I'm looking for the expected value of a function that takes the maximum value of each of these functions for a random value (uniform distribution of integer values, including borders) in each of their domains.

```
g() = max(
    easy      ( rand(1,   10  ) ),
    normal    ( rand(10,  25  ) ),
    hard      ( rand(25,  100 ) ),
    impossible( rand(200, 500 ) ),
    insane    ( rand(500, 1000) )
);
```

E(g) = ?

Comment: You can provide link to picture. Then somebody edit your post.

Comment: url: http://s13.postimg.org/vwvc2pc5z/bonus_per_hour_chart.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand precisely what do you mean by $rand(N,M)$ but if you mean that it is random variable uniformely distributed between N and M than insane allways will be maximum as it is greater or equal than all other values.

Then expected value of max = expected value of insane = 750.

EDIT. Update to question was made.

Calculate distribution function of max:
$$F(x) = P(max < x) = P(easy < x) \cdot P(normal < x) \cdot P(hard < x) \cdot P(impossible < x) \cdot P(insane < x)$$
To know that you have to know
$$P(insane < x) = P( 25 \cdot 3600/( Y * 3.6 + 60) < x) = P(Y > 25 \cdot 3600/(3.6 \cdot x)- \frac{60}{3.6}) = \min(\max(\frac{1000 - 25 \cdot 3600/(3.6 \cdot x) + \frac{60}{3.6}}{1000-500},0),1)$$. Here we used that Y is uniformely distributed between 500 and 1000
Same calculations for other functions and you have F(x) as function of x.

Then $E(max) = \int x \cdot F'(x) dx $.

There are a lot of formulas here but as I understand you need solution but not analytical form so you can program it in language you prefer.

Comment: Indeed I mean a random variable uniformely distributed in [N,M].
However, easy(), normal(), hard(), impossible() & insane() do not just output these random values, but return a different value, dependant upon the random values.
I created a graph showing the functions, but SE won't let me post it yet since I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Then you have to describe this functions in text.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Ok. With this formulation still insane(x) is greater than all other functions. And argument of insane is greater that all other arguments so insane i s still max.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in building the functions. I think they should be correct now.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explenation helped me a lot!

Three notes though:

- the value 3.66 should be 3.6 (as per my updated functions)
- in you min(max(...)) equation you forgot brackets around 25*3600/(3.6.x)-60/3.6)
- the devisor 500 was a little confusing, as it is (1000-500) (=max-min)

Comment: Yes maybe forgot. So you understand the idea. PS if youa re satisfied with answer you can upvote it and/or mark as appropriate.

Comment: I accepted your answer. If you'd be so kind as to fix the small errors, humatiny will be gratefull ;)

Comment: Updated. Thank you for comments.